# The operator norm is defined based on the supremum or equivalently the maximum.

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, functional-analysis, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

The definition is

$$\|A\| = \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \max \left\{ \|Ax\|: \|x\|=1 \right\}$$

but how is maximum coming in place?

Comment: If one writes ${ \| A x\| \over \| x \| }$ then this is only defined for $x \neq 0$ and, a priori, it is not immediate that there is a maximiser. When one writes the $\|x \| \le 1$ ( or $= 1$) version then in finite dimensions a maximiser exists so we can write $\max$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume here you mean that you are working in a finite dimensional normed space. In that case the sphere $\{x: ||x||=1\}$ is a compact set, and since linear transformations in finite dimensional normed spaces are continuous, this implies that $||Ax||$ has a maximum on that sphere.

This is no longer true in infinite dimensional normed spaces. There you really must write supremum, not maximum.